# employment data - Pivot table, placing all employment data in one row

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Hi so I have table as following

| employee id | job | start_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1/1/2021 |
| 1 | def | 5/1/2021 |
| 2 | xyz | 6/1/2021 |
| 2 | rfd | 8/1/2021 |
| 2 | hgf | 7/1/2021 |
| 2 | esd | 1/1/1999 |

I was wonder if there's a way I could pivot the table and layup all job and date at the same row,

| employee id | job_a | start_dt_ a | job_b | start_dt_b | job_c | start_dt_c | job_d | start_dt_d | job_e | start_dt_e | job_f | start_dt_f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1/1/2021 | def | 5/1/2021 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | xyz | 6/1/2021 | rfd | 8/1/2021 | hgf | 7/1/2021 | esd | 1/1/1999 |  |  |  |  |

(table name 'JOB')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *Conditional Aggregation* along with `ROW_NUMBER()` Analytic function such as

```sql
WITH j AS
(  
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY start_dt) AS rn,
        j.*
   FROM job j
)
SELECT employee_id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN job END) AS job_a,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN start_dt END) AS start_dt_a,  
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN job END) AS job_b,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN start_dt END) AS start_dt_b,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN job END) AS job_c,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN start_dt END) AS start_dt_c,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN job END) AS job_d,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN start_dt END) AS start_dt_d              
  FROM j
 GROUP BY employee_id
 ORDER BY employee_id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=73fb8d4334a6e9534aeeda7a49125442)</kbd>

P.S. *the logic for the sorting for current result set is not clear enough*